# Google App Engine with maven : I must restart the local devappserver to see any changes in a JSP or servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, servlets

I created a Maven project with the Google App Engine archetype. When I start the devappserver, my web application prints very well at localhost:8080 within my web browser. But once that the server devappserver is started and that I do some changes in my JSP files or servlets and that I do a refresh in my web browser, I don't see any changes. I'm obliged to restart myself the server devappserver in Eclipse. It's very a pity.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: That's expected behavior. You can try integrating with JRebel.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options here is to configure Eclipse's project build path.
If you have a web project then you can change output folder for your /src/main/java classes to be /target//WEB-INF/classes.
Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source tab and change the 'Output Folder' property for the /src/main/java folder in the 'Source folders on build path' list.

This way every time you change source code Eclipse recompiles it and copies to the output folder.
Then AppEngine (effectively Jetty server) picks up the change
This solves the issue with servlets (apparently, Java classes in your war/web project).
I'm currently struggling with having JSP reloaded as well.

Sure if you have the war project depending on other artifacts those won't be updated if you are running the web app project. In this case one of the solutions is to use JRebel, as noted in the comments

Just recalled one thing: you don't have to run AppEngine Maven plugin for development per se. You can configure project via Maven, have build via Maven.
But for continuous development simply create a new AppEngine server in Eclipse. Then deploy your project to the server and run/debug it.
This way you have automatic republishing of all the changes and you don't even have to configure Eclipse's output folders as I mentioned above (to be used with appengine Maven plugin running the server against your 'target' folder)

Answer (score 0):

Use netbeans instead. I am using netbeans 8.0 beta and rc1, and use nbappengine-7.4.x-gae1.8.x-3.0.2.zip from https://code.google.com/p/nb-gaelyk-plugin/downloads/list, gae 1.9.0. Much easier to use for me.

Comment: Somebody let me know if in the future the eclipse plugin is as convenient as Netbeans.